# How to get all email id's of friends which are in friendsList from facebook

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone.my question is How to get all email id's of friends which are in friendsList from facebook while using Graph API in iPhone? I am able to get all the pictures,name,first name and last name of the friends which are in friends list except the email id's how can we do this If any body know this please help me.IF any body provide some code for this it will be helpful for me....

Answer (score 0):

You can't, e-mail addresses aren't available via API for friends due to privacy risks.

See the facebook [Permissions Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not possible to get the email addresses of Facebook users other than the user of your app (ie. the person who authorizes your app and for whom you get an access_token), not even Friends of the user. Even extended permissions won’t help here.